# Google Calendar API Insert Event

Tags: c#, google-app-engine

I can read calendar list and event list. There is any problem with login.

I trying add new event, i will not get any exception but never adding.

**How can i create new event ?**

My code (I can not find v3 sample for .NET, I made up this, could be wrong)

```
Event newEvent = new Event();
newEvent.Summary = tb_Title.Text;
newEvent.Description = tb_Desc.Text;
newEvent.Start = new EventDateTime();
newEvent.Start.DateTime = dateTimePicker1.Value;
newEvent.End = new EventDateTime();
newEvent.End.DateTime = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddHours(1);

calendarService.Events.Insert(newEvent, calendarId);
```

Comment: Try it from the oauth2 playground so you understand the correct parameters

Comment: I get **manage access** not read only mode, in my opinion `calendarService.Events.Insert` is wrong method but i cannot find anything

Comment: what does that have to do with my suggestion?

Comment: i am using `CalendarService.Scope.Calendar` not `CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly` on login i will get access but i don't know where is the problem.  _i will not get any exception_

Comment: like I said, follow my first comment first and post results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can read calendar list and event list. There is any problem with
>   login.

This means that your OAuth2 authentication worked, but you still may have chosen the wrong scope/write permissions.

> I trying add new event, i will not get any exception but never adding.

This is because you aren't executing your query. You need to use an `Execute()` method.

> My code (I can not find v3 sample for .NET, I made up this, could be wrong)

The properties you chose work fine, and the dates are formatted correctly. The only thing you need to change is to execute your query with an `Execute()` method. He's an example based on your code:

```
Event newEvent = new Event();

using (frmAddEvent frmAddEvent = new frmAddEvent()){
    frmAddEvent.ShowDialog();
    newEvent.Summary = frmAddEvent.txtTitle.Text;
    newEvent.Description = frmAddEvent.txtDesc.Text;
    newEvent.Start = new EventDateTime();
    newEvent.Start.DateTime = frmAddEvent.dateTimePicker1.Value;
    newEvent.End = new EventDateTime();
    newEvent.End.DateTime = frmAddEvent.dateTimePicker1.Value.AddHours(1);
    if (frmAddEvent.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK) {
        var eventResult = await service.Events.Insert(newEvent, calendarID).ExecuteAsync();
    }
}
```

This query returns the event that you just created rather than a status type.

Comment: Yep its true. I solved that but thanks for answer. Only need `Execute()`